# Autocompletado de datos con Booststrap Typeahead + Spring MVC y JavaScript desde la base de datos

Tags: java, javascript, bootstrap, spring, spring-mvc

Estoy intentando hacer un autocompletado de datos utilizando el typeahead de bootstrap.

La idea es que, cuando escriba un código en el input, haga una búsqueda desde la base de datos. Al seleccionar una de ellas, automáticamente me rellene el código y el nombre.

He intentado hacerlo, pero no lo he logrado, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

**Este es mi código HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <label for="cuenta_codigo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cuenta Contable:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
          <form:input id="cuenta_codigo" path="cuenta.ccuenta_cod" cssClass="form-control" placeholder="Código" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <form:input id="cuenta_nombre" path="cuenta.vcuenta_nombre" cssClass="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Este en mi Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/master/cuenta/ajax", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<AutoType> getAjax(@RequestParam("type") String type, @RequestParam("param") String param){

    List<AutoType> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        lista = cuentaService.getCuentaAjaxByCode(param);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

    return lista;
}
```

**Este es mi Código JavaScript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cuenta_codigo').typeahead({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/master/cuenta/ajax",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    param: request.param
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Si es necesario os dejo el DAO Implement y el Service Implement**

Dao Implement

```
@Override
public List<Cuenta> getCuentaAjax(String code) {
    String namedQuery = "Cuenta.getAjaxByCode";
    List<FilterHQL> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(new FilterHQL("ccuenta_cod", code+"%"));
    return hibernateUtil.fetchListByParamHQL(filters, Cuenta.class, namedQuery);
}
```

Service Implement

```
@Override
public List<AutoType> getCuentaAjaxByCode(String code) {
    List<AutoType> json = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Cuenta> lista = cuentaDao.getCuentaAjax(code);
    for (Cuenta cuenta : lista) {
        json.add(new AutoType(cuenta.getCcuenta_cod(), cuenta.getVcuenta_nombre()));
    }
    return json;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un poco más de información? La idea no es que alguien resuelva un problema en tu código en tu lugar. ¿Intentaste depurarlo? ¿Dónde está fallando? ¿En qué parte de toda la lógica no se está obteniendo el resultado esperado? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Hola, no me sale ningún error, simplemente no me coge los datos de la base de datos.

Comment: Hola, no me sale ningún error, simplemente no me coge los datos de la base de datos.
La idea es que cuando escriba un código en la caja de texto **<form:input id="cuenta_codigo" path="cuenta.ccuenta_cod" cssClass="form-control" placeholder="Código" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead"/>** me muestra los códigos disponibles de esa tabla y al seleccionar uno me complete el código y el nombre.

Answer (score 0):

Incluye en el metodo getAjax() el Model, tipo:

```
public List<AutoType> getAjax(@RequestParam("type") String type,
         @RequestParam("param") String param, Model model)
```

Hecho esto, envia la lista deseada a la vista nombrandolo "data" en lugar del return porque lo que quieres devolver es un json, ejemplo:

```
model.addAttribute("data", lista);
```

Edito:

Deberia quedar asi, es como lo tienes?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/master/cuenta/ajax", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<AutoType> getAjax(@RequestParam("type") String type, @RequestParam("param") String param, Model model){

    List<AutoType> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        lista = cuentaService.getCuentaAjaxByCode(param);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

    model.addAttribute("data", lista); 
}
```

El retorno al jsp lo hace el model.addAttribute() siempre y cuando la lista tenga algun valor, deberias comprobar si la lista recibe los valores adecuados y no estas devolviendo una lista vacia en primer lugar.

Por cierto, imagino que tienes agregado el bean para los json?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Una vez comprobado que la lista tiene los valores adecuados, la lista será tratada como "data" dentro del typeahead pues es como lo estas nombrando, deberías rastrear si lo estas tratando de manera adecuada en el js del jsp

Comment: Hola @Stefan Nolde, podrías ser más especifico por favor.

Comment: @JRupailla eso tienes que pedir al autor de la respuesta, yo solamente ayudé en reformatear el código para que queda más fácil de leerlo ;)

Comment: Hola @Jaimito, incluí el Model al método, pero es necesario tener un retorno.

Comment: Al parecer el método no funciona, aun no me cogen los datos.

Comment: Hola @Jaimito, quisiera saber si mi Script esta correcto.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cuenta_codigo').typeahead({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/master/cuenta/ajax",
                    autoSelect: true,
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        param: request.param
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });